# Creating a relative frequency histogram and superimposing a normal distribution curve

Tags: r, histogram, normal-distribution

Basically, I have trouble plotting the relative frequency histogram, as when I plot the data my y axis always becomes greater than one. I also want to superimpose a normal distribution on top however it never seems to work.

What I have produced so far: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxTqW.jpg

I have tried multiple methods in plotting the histogram such as `hist()`, `truehist()` and `plot()` etc.

```
truehist(aest,freq=TRUE, xlab = "Average Est", col="blue")
curve(dnorm(x,mean(aest),sd(aest)),col="red", add=TRUE, lwd=2)
legend("topright",legend=c(paste("median = ",toString(mean(aest))),paste("mean = ",toString(median(aest))),paste("SD = ",toString(sd(aest)))), cex=0.65)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a density plot, not a frequency one. Try `hist` with

```
freq = FALSE
```

And you'll get the result you want. I don't have your data, but subbing some random data I have in it will look like so:

```
hist(move$dist,freq=FALSE, xlab = "Average Est", col="blue")
curve(dnorm(x,mean(move$dist),sd(move$dist)),col="red", add=TRUE, lwd=2)
legend("topright",
       legend=c(paste("median = ",toString(mean(move$dist))),
                paste("mean = ",toString(median(move$dist))),
                paste("SD = ",toString(sd(move$dist)))), 
       cex=0.65)
```

[image]

Or you can do `truehist`, but then the parameter isn't `freq` it is

```
prob = TRUE
```

which will look something like this:

```
truehist(move$dist,prob = TRUE, xlab = "Average Est", col="blue", nbins = "fd")
curve(dnorm(x,mean(move$dist),sd(move$dist)),col="red", add=TRUE, lwd=2)
legend("topright",
       legend=c(paste("median = ",toString(mean(move$dist))),
                paste("mean = ",toString(median(move$dist))),
                paste("SD = ",toString(sd(move$dist)))), 
       cex=0.65)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however when I tried it with "prob = TRUE" using truehist, my range is still [0,50000].

Comment: I edited my answer to show `hist` and `truehist` both working with data I provided. Did `hist` give you the expected results? Can you post a picture of the `truehist` plot with `prob = TRUE` so I can try to diagnose what's going on?